# Put multiple arrays into first key PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this result when use `array_chunk` to split one json to separate arrays. I use it because i need to add in each array one last element (adding new row for handsome table). So... the result after all of my code is this: I use Laravel PHP

```
array:6 [
  0 => array:6 [
    0 => {#402
      +"row": 0
      +"col": 0
      +"rowspan": 1
      +"colspan": 1
      +"text": "Column 1"
      +"color": ""
    }
    1 => {#398
      +"row": 0
      +"col": 1
      +"rowspan": 1
      +"colspan": 1
      +"text": "Column 2"
      +"color": ""
    }
  ]
  1 => array:6 [
    2 => {#400
      +"row": 1
      +"col": 0
      +"rowspan": 1
      +"colspan": 1
      +"text": "Row 1"
      +"color": ""
    }
    3 => {#399
      +"row": 1
      +"col": 1
      +"rowspan": 1
      +"colspan": 1
      +"text": "Row 1"
      +"color": ""
    }
  ]
  2 => array:6 [
    4 => {#406
      +"row": 2
      +"col": 0
      +"rowspan": 1
      +"colspan": 1
      +"text": "Row 2"
      +"color": ""
    }
    5 => {#407
      +"row": 2
      +"col": 1
      +"rowspan": 1
      +"colspan": 1
      +"text": "Row 2"
      +"color": ""
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to put ALL from 1 to 2 into first 0 so it will be something like this:

```
array:6 [
 0 => array:6 [
  0 => {#402.....} 1 => {#398.....}
  1 => ....
  2 => ....
  3 => ....
  4 => ....
  5 => ....     
]
```

Please help how to do it.

Comment: Show us what you have tried in order to solve this.

Comment: Some foreach, array_push....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answere:

```
$o = $result[0];
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($result); $i++) {
            foreach ($result[$i] as $a => $s) {
                array_push($o, $s);
            }
        }

print_r($o);
```